# MySQL ORDER BY Twice (by same field)

Tags: mysql

I have a series of events with dates, as follows:

- Event 1, 1/1/2014
- Event 2, 1/2/2014
- Event 3, 1/3/2014

Say I wanted the most recent two events, in chronological order. If I ran:

`SELECT * FROM 'table_name' ORDER BY 'Date' ASC LIMIT 2`

I would get the following results:

- Event 1, 1/1/2014
- Event 2, 1/2/2014

But this is incorrect, as Event 3 is the most recent event. So I therefore change ASC to DESC:

`SELECT * FROM 'table_name' ORDER BY 'Date' DESC LIMIT 2`

And I get the following results:

- Event 3, 1/3/2014
- Event 2, 1/2/2014

This is the correct result set, but they're backwards. I would like the most recent event last...but I can't simply use `ORDER BY 'Date'` a second time. Is there a way to limit my results (via a `LIMIT` and an `ORDER BY`, and then use a second `ORDER BY`on the remaining results?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: this is mysql, so those aren't dates ;-)

Comment: True, although I find this more readable than datetime notation. I didn't think the notation was as important as the concept, which was sorting twice.

Comment: jake, @Strawberry made a good point. you shouldn't store the dates in this format because ordering by a string date instead of a datetime field means you will get incorrect results. if you would like to know how and or why I can show you... but as a rule of thumb its better to store the data as the datatype its meant to be stored as :)

Comment: I don't actually store them that way! I just posted it the sample data in a readable fashion for StackOverflow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

an even faster way is to just do one select. use UNION syntax to order a second time. try it out!

```
(SELECT * 
 FROM events 
 ORDER BY date DESC 
 LIMIT 2
)ORDER BY date ASC;
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/208a5/1)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * FROM events ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 2) AS table_alias 
ORDER BY date ASC
```

You need to have a table alias for a sub query

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

actually, you can

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT * FROM 'table_name' ORDER BY 'Date' DESC LIMIT 2
)
ORDER BY 'Date' ASC
```

Comment: there is no need to do two selects... and this query will throw an error if you run it